# Six variables. System of equations.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polynomials

$$
\begin{align}    
   x & =\frac{R+\frac{G+B}{-2}}{R+G+B} \\[10pt]
    y & =\frac{\frac{(G-B) \sqrt{3}}{2}}{R+G+B} \\[10pt]
    z & =R+G+B
\end{align}
$$

How do I get the formula for $R$, $G$, and $B$?

I have the $x$, $y$, and $z$ to inputs and I want the $R$, $G$, and $B$ outputs. It absolutely cannot have $R$, $G$, or $B$ on the right of the equal sign.

Also, if there is a more simplified formula for the ones I've supplied, feel free to post those.

When $RGB(0,0,0)$ then $xyz(0,0,0)$ instead of a divide-by-zero error.

$R$, $G$, and $B$ will always be a integer between 0 and 255.

Comment: First you need to edit your post to clarify what you equations are. You are using the `/` sign too liberally. You can type a fraction like $\frac{a}{b}$ by typing `$\frac{a}{b}$`. See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more detail on how to typeset mathematics on this site. Second, what have you tried yourself to answer this question? You should include in your post any attempts you've made to solve this.

Comment: Multiply the top and bottom of the LHS of $x$ and $y$ by $R + G + B$, rearrange, and you'll end up with a system of 3 linear equations in three variables.

Comment: Please view the LaTeX tutorial here:

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Also, can you post the nine equations as an `answer' to your own question, and then we can see your progress!

Comment: You're just going to have to catch the case when $\langle R, G, B \rangle = \langle 0, 0, 0 \rangle$, because if $z = 0$ then $x$ and $y$ are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same approach as user3002473 and continuing the simplifications, the calculations simplify to $$R=\frac{z}{3} (2 x +1)$$ $$G=\frac{z}{3}  \left(\sqrt{3} y-x+1\right)$$ $$B=-\frac{z}{3}  \left(x+\sqrt{3} y-1\right)$$

Comment: This is much shorter and less confusing. I guess I'm off to study Matrices, because they keep popping up in my life. Especially when crossing color theory with computers.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
(R + G + B)x = R-\frac12(G + B)\quad \implies\quad (x - 1)R + \left(x + \frac12\right)G + \left(x + \frac12\right)B = 0 \\
(R + G + B)y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(G - B)\quad \implies\quad yR + \left(y - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)G + \left(y + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)B = 0 \\
R + G + B = z
$$
which is a set of linear equations. We can solve this by putting the following matrix in row echelon form:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
x - 1 & \displaystyle x + \frac12 & \displaystyle x + \frac12 & 0 \\
y & \displaystyle y - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \displaystyle y + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & z \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
The solution to these equations appears to be
$$
R = \frac{z}{x'}(x' - 1) \\
G = \frac{zy'}{x'(y' - 1)} \\
B = \frac{z}{x'(1 - y')}
$$
where I have defined
$$
x' = 1 - \frac{x + \frac12}{x - 1} \\
y' = \frac{x'y + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{x'y - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
$$

Comment: Well, it's an augmented matrix. The fourth column represents the values on the RHS of the three equations.

Comment: What are you talking about, this is the equation you wrote, is it not? The second one above? If the values you wrote are correct test values, then perhaps there's a typo in one of your initial equations.

Comment: $y = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}(G - B)}{2}}{R + G + B} \implies (R + G + B)y = \frac{\sqrt{3}(G - B)}{2} \implies Ry + Gy + By - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}G + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}B = 0 \implies Ry + G(y - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) + B(y + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = 0$

Comment: Have you taken linear algebra?

Comment: I made it to calculus. but it was 10 years ago. I haven't used math in soo long.

Comment: Performing Gaussian elimination on a set of linear equations, which allows you to solve said set of linear equations, is the same as reducing the equivalent augmented matrix to row echelon form. Khan academy has a good introduction to the mechanics behind it if you're interested.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the problem seems to be? Are you inputting values that aren't outputting the correct values? Are you getting undefined results?

Comment: Try the new version, I made a mistake before.

Comment: Already removed. Also removed an extraneous division and multiplication by $1 - y'$ from the equation for $R$, make sure you didn't add that into your code by accident.